# Counting times user logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to count the amount of times a user logged in. Here's how I'm attempting to do this:

Call the user with

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

After that, I'm trying to access DB for the amount of times the user logged in using

```
$logincount = $user->logincount;
```

and then I'm trying to increment the variable with this line

```
++$logincount;
```

and finally i'm trying to save the user and return a redirect to the intended page:

```
$user->save();
return Redirect::intended('/');
```

After I login and check the db, the number in the "logincount" field is not incremented and I am logged in and redirected to the correct page. I datadumped/vardumped the $user variable and it shows that the user is still 0. Not sure what the issue is, as I have just started learning to program. I would really appreciate some help. Thx!

Here's the entire function:

```
public function postSignIn() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ));

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //Redirect to sign in page
        return Redirect::route('home')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    } else {

        //Checks if user checked true or false
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
        //Attempt use sign in
        $auth     = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
        ), $remember);

        if ($auth) {

            //Increment login count
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $logincount = $user->logincount;
            ++$logincount;
            $user->save();

            //Redirect to the Intended Page
            return Redirect::intended('/');

        } else {
            return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'Email or Password Incorrect or account not activated');
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'There was a problem signing you in :(');
}
```

Comment: What you are incrementing is a local copy if the counter's value. Not the counter.

Comment: `$logincount = $user->logincount;` should be `$user->logincount++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Eloquent's [`increment`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1280-L1283) method:

```
$user->increment('logincount');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the local variable.

```
$logincount = $user->logincount;
++$logincount;
```

Should just be:

```
$user->logincount++
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here, is fetching the $user->logincount number from the database and putting it into a variable. You then increase **the variable's** value by one instead of the user's actual login count.

You should do something like this instead:

```
$user->logincount = $user->logincount + 1;
$user->save();

// or
$user->logincount++;
$user->save();
```